# How to update listview in for loop in asynk task

Tags: java, android, multithreading, user-interface, android-asynctask

I'm reading some text from *HttpUrlConnection* request and putting it in ArrayList every iteration of a loop.

All works perfect, except items in ListView don't updating in UI after every iteration of a loop (only at the end).

I'm tried next 4 methods: `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), listView.invalidateViews(), runOnUiThread(), onPostExecute()` nothing helps.

**Here is my code:**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<String> news = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    static JSONArray array;
    NewsUnpacker unpacker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

        String link = "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty";
        NewsLoader newsLoader = new NewsLoader();

        array = null;
        try {
            array = newsLoader.execute(link).get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headers);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        final int size = 15;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

            try {
                unpacker = new NewsUnpacker(this);
                String info = unpacker.execute("https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/" + array.get(i) + ".json?print=pretty").get();

                if (info == null) {
                    unpacker.cancel(true);
                    return;
                }

                news.add(info);
                headers.add(info.split(System.lineSeparator())[0]);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.invalidateViews();

                unpacker.cancel(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
    }

    static class NewsUnpacker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        MainActivity activity;

        NewsUnpacker(MainActivity activity) {
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String info = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                int data;
                while ((data = reader.read()) != -1)
                    builder.append((char) data);

                String title, urlParam;
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(builder.toString());

                title = object.get("title").toString();
                urlParam = object.get("url").toString();
                info = title + System.lineSeparator() + urlParam;
                System.out.println(info);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return info;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }

    static class NewsLoader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> {
        JSONArray array = null;

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                int data;
                while ((data = reader.read()) != -1)
                    builder.append((char) data);

                array = new JSONArray(builder.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return array;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not Android developer specially, but maybe a solution is to use `ObservableList` as model like we do with `ObservableCollection` in C# to refresh the content of the `ListView` in live with _MVVM (model view, view model)_. You don't "touch" the list view content, all must be done by the observable list. [ListView JavaFx 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

Comment: Add the model `ObservableList` to the view, and after, loop on your data and add or remove them from the model. Not important if it is sync or async, data should be shown when they are modified and available in the observable list. _Documentation: List, ArrayList is not the recommended approach because it's a copy and it's not reflecting the data changes_